# Alicloud node memory Requested/Limited/Used

Tags: kubernetes, memory, alibaba-cloud

We have a test cluster of 3 nodes on Alicloud

We haven't set any memory limits, per namespace or per pod

However, when looking at the nodes in the alicloud console, we see a `Requested/Limited/Used` set for the memory. The pods are running out of memory when the `Used` is over the `Limited` threshold

Does anyone know where this limit comes from? It seems to be different for each one of our node, so it creates an arbitrary limit per pod?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I cant find any relevant information where are your current default limits come from.. but anyway you should solve your issue somehow.

I can suggest you manually set required limits to avoid OOMs in future. What you will need to do - is to calculate approximate resource usage and correctly apply limits

This can help:

[Kubernetes: Assign Memory Resources and Limits to Containers](https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/kubernetes-assign-memory-resources-and-limits-to-containers_594830), especially this part

> LimitRange for Memory
>
> Kubernetes administrators can define RAM limits for their nodes.
>
> These limits are enforced at higher priority over how much RAM your
> Pod declares and wants to use.
>
> Let's define our first LimitRange : 25Mi RAM as min, 200Mi as max.

```
nano myRAM-LimitRange.yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: LimitRange
metadata:
  name: my-ram-limit
spec:
  limits:
  - max:
      memory: 200Mi
    min:
      memory: 25Mi
```

Comment: We're still in early prototype, so we don't really want to set some limits now. Although I get your point, and we should indeed work on this at some point.

My question was really about where the limits are coming from. For example, the middle node is limited at 27% -> Where does that number comes from?